# wordpress and angular theme update post list on when new post is published

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, angular

Hi i'm new in Angular 4 and I want to use it to build a WordPress theme using the wp-api. I start with the [ng-wp-theme](https://github.com/stuartkuentzel/ng-wp-theme) but I and all its working fine, but I need that hen a new post is publish the post list page updates itself without reload the page. I saw some tutorials about the http services in angular but I dont find any solution to this, maybe its a Wordpress api issue and not the Angular part.

**here is the service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Post } from './post';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class PostsService {

  private _wpBase = environment.wpBase;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getPosts(): Observable<Post[]> {
      return this.http.get<Post[]>(this._wpBase + 'posts');
  }

  getPost(slug: string): Observable<Post[]> {
      return this.http.get<Post[]>(this._wpBase + `posts?slug=${slug}`);
  }
}
```

**and the controller:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Post } from '../post';
import { PostsService } from '../posts.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-list',
  templateUrl: './post-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-list.component.css'],
  providers: [PostsService]
})

export class PostListComponent implements OnInit {

  public posts: Post[];

  constructor( private postsService: PostsService, private router: Router ) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    this.postsService.getPosts().subscribe(
      (posts: Post[]) => this.posts = posts,
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => err.error instanceof Error ? console.log('An error occurred:', err.error.message) : console.log(`Backend returned code ${err.status}, body was: ${err.error}`));

  }
  selectPost(slug) {
    this.router.navigate([slug]);
  }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you need a polling service or a websocket. Angular doesn't know when new posts are created in WordPress until you reload the `/posts` endpoint.

Comment: Polling is probably the only thing that's going to work here. Having looked at it recently, I don't believe that there's anything in the wp-api that supports a websocket.

Comment: So there is not solution? at the moment?